# How to generate random session for SSH ID in Linux?

Tags: linux, session, ssh

I am searching about random session ID for ssh in Linux.

If someone accessses with SSH the session ID increases sequentially, How to generate a random session ID?

Example. setting in OS or Include Library, ETC...

Thank you for your reading this quesition. :)

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). What is the real goal? Why do you think you need a random ID?

Comment: For session security
I have to change the ID values that increase sequentially to increase randomly. @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: Can you explain how that makes it more secure? (Are you thinking Linux session IDs work like HTTP session cookies, where just knowing the ID grants access to the session? They **don't** work like that.)

Comment: @user1686 thank you for answer :)
now i got it. can you please answer my qustion? i want to adopt your answer.